# expected workspace package to exist for \"sane\""

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I got the project from the github and want to install the node_modules by using "yarn install".

When I enter the yarn install, the terminal came out the result as shown as the picture. As a reference, my node version is 12.18.0, yarn version 1.22.4, and npm version 6.14.5. May I know is the version not compatible or somethings else problem?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Same issue using lerna.
Assumed it's the yarn version problem.
Under project folder, I tried rolling back yarn version:

```
yarn policies set-version 1.19.0
// (or 1.18.0)
```

Yarn [polies documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/policies/)

Solved for my case: yarn ^3.22.0, node v14.4.0

Comment: how to reset back

Comment: You can reset by removing the `.yarnrc` file that is created when you run the above command, or removing the relevant configuration setting if you do need it.

Answer (score 8):

A quicker solution is to use:

```
npx yarn@1.19.0 add your-deps-here
```

Comment: is there a fix for this for v1.22.x?